# Do we need dockerfile or cloudbuild.yaml while choosing the cloudbuild trigger configuration as Buildpacks?

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, continuous-integration, google-cloud-build, buildpack

I have been trying to deploy the typescript code on google cloudrun & I wanted to use cloudbuild trigger configuration as build packs. I was able to create the trigger & while running the trigger I can see it building the app also on cloud run successfully. But when I try to access the url of cloud run , it is showing error as:- "Oops, something went wrong…
Continuous deployment has been set up, but your repository has failed to build and deploy.
This revision is a placeholder until your code successfully builds and deploys to the Cloud Run service cee-portal in europe-west4 of the GCP project".
[image]

My trigger configuration is :
[image]
Is it essential to have cloudbuild or docker file for creating the cloudbuild trigger?
I thought if I am choosing buildpacks as configuration I don't have to provide these files.
Please correct me if i am wrong here...

Comment: I'm getting this error even after putting dockerfile  & choose docker as configuration in cloudbuild trigger. I am not getting why this issue is happening.

Comment: You don't need a Cloudbuild.yaml or a Dockerfile with Buildpacks config.

Comment: Do we need to install buildpacks on gcloud project in order to use the Buildpacks config.

Comment: Nothing to install, but config to add to your project if you want that Buildpacks read and use your conf

Comment: You mean there is some conf file which needs to be added, can you tell me how it looks like

Comment: You can add a `Procfile`, especially in Python, to override/define the entrypoint of your app. Sample here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-gunicorn#adding-gunicorn-to-your-application

Comment: It is about heroku whereas I'm deploying on Google cloud & I'm deploying React App on google cloud  cloudrun

Comment: Procfile is used by Buildpacks. The problem is that I have difficulties to find documentation on that. I shared the heroku doc because it is great on that topic.